# Text Replace in Regular Expression In VBA Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba

There is a formula:

```
SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Water",'Pivot'!$A$3,"cCode",A2),GETPIVOTDATA("Water",'Pivot'!$A$3,"cCode",A2))
```

and **the content of the formula doesn't matter**. I would like to **replace** all instances of `GETPIVOTDATA("Water")` with `GETPIVOTDATA("Soft-Drink")` using regular expression.

Comment: You should just use `Find & Replace` and look inside formulas (which will also work on a range object larger than a single cell). No need for regular expressions.

Comment: No, I need to do it with Reg Exp.